# IText font not subsetting or embedding

Tags: itext

I am on the mainframe platform and uploaded the arial.ttf from Windows.
 I used the following code for the font, but the font does not show SUBSETTED or EMBEDDED in Adobe.
 I even tried to add font.getBaseFont to force it to embed.

Any reason why it would not embed or subset?

```
String font1 = "arial.ttf";                                                
FontFactory.register(font1,"myfont");                                      
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(font1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);       
Font font =  FontFactory.getFont("arial");   

font.getBaseFont().setSubset(true);
```

Adobe doc show the following font information:

```
Type truetype
Encoding Ansi
Actual Font: ArialMT
Actual Font type: TrueType
```

Comment: BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
Font font = new Font(bf, 12);

Comment: Thanks Bruno. You were right I need to add                                          Font font = new Font(bf, 12);                                                                                                     Also the font in Adobe showing 'Unknown' was due to a wrong encoding, unrelated to iText, which caused a corruption in the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `BaseFont` object `bf`, but you aren't doing anything with it. One would expect that you do this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(pathToFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
```

In this case, `font` would make sure that a subset of the font is embedded because the encoding is `Identity-H` and iText always embeds a subset of a font with that encoding.

As you aren't doing anything with `bf`, it is as if the line isn't present. In that case, we are left with:

```
String font1 = "arial.ttf";                                                
FontFactory.register(font1,"myfont");    
Font font =  FontFactory.getFont("arial");
```

Assuming that the path to `arial.ttf` is correct, and that the alias of that font is `"arial"`, you are now creating a font with the default encoding (Ansi), the default font size (12) and the default embedding (false).

That is in line with what is shown in Adobe Reader. If you want a subset of the font to be embedded, you need at least:

```
Font font =  FontFactory.getFont("arial", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

In answer to your question: the reason why the font is not embedded by iText is the fact that you are not telling iText to embed the font.